# How do I subdivide smooth in blender 2.8?

Tags: subdivision-surface

Previously I could that in specials menu, but it seems that there is no such option in 2.8 version.

Comment: did you try searching for subdivide smooth in the search menu (F3) or (SPACE) [depends on how you set it up in the preferences] when in edit mode?

Answer (score 12):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

It appears that they have removed the *Subdivide Smooth* option in 2.80 (at least  in the version I have). However, it's always actually been a bit redundant as the *Subdivide* tool has a *Smoothness* slider that, when set to 1, behaves the exact same way as Subdivide smooth did. Plus, Blender will use your most recently used settings when subdividing, so it will the *Subdivide* tool will act exactly like *Subdivide Smooth* until you tell it otherwise (or close Blender). The *Subdivide* tool should still be in the specials menu like before.

Comment: Original objet : https://i.imgur.com/3dZLt7x.png
Subdivide smooth : https://i.imgur.com/bdmZ0dH.jpg
Original objet : subdivision surface modifier https://i.imgur.com/H7TTDcj.jpg
Better roundness in subdivision surface that in subdivide operation https://i.imgur.com/fUXVJIa.png

Comment: where is the specials menu ? 2.8 is driving me crazy!!!!!

Comment: It's now in the right click context menu. Just right click on the object in edit mode and it should be the first option.

Comment: For anyone who may be in the same position as I was (using a Mac Magic Mouse with no right click) you can change the right mouse action to keyboard shortcut 'w' under Preferences - Keymap - Mesh - Call menu

Answer (score 3):

Select the object, left click and press subdivide. Then click on subdivide that appeared on the bottom left and turn the smoothness all the way up.

Comment: With the Blender 2.8 default settings it's right click, just in case somebody gets confused.